# Question of the Week #33

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 33 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this one quite interesting:

> #### [Why is there so much hype about Virtualization these days?](https://superuser.com/questions/351790/why-is-there-so-much-hype-about-virtualization-these-days)
>
> Virtual machine, Virtual server, Virtual disk, etc......
>
> It doesn't make much sense to me why someone would want to make their things "virtual" when basically that adds another layer to everything (which in most cases will make it run more slow).
>
> What's the purpose of Virtualization in the multiple cases above?

I'm still impressed it hasn't been closed, because the question itself is a bit vague. The answers however are excellent and provide many good reasons to use virtualization these days.

Comment: I'm sure I can do a summarizing blog post if Wil does not have the time!

Comment: OK, go! If you can do a quick synopsis, that would be great, but do ask Wil if he's interested in writing anything about it.

Comment: Slhck can you also include briefly what the top votes question, answer, and highest viewed post are? Info should be easy enough to find in /tools.

Answer (score 1):

## [What does wwws mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/353245/what-does-wwws-mean)

> I've seen a couple of sites that use wwws in their domain, for
>   example: wwws.mint.com and wwws.whitehouse.gov. I'm sure it has
>   something to do with an extra layer of security.
>
> What does it mean and what is it used for? Why do only a handful of
>   sites use it?

An average question, but the answers are *great*!

Comment: Got submitted a bit too late to really get any views, but we have a post about it already written!